# Vue.js socket.io v-for list items data miss assignment

Tags: socket.io, vue.js

Hello guys I have a weird issue here where the following code

```
created() {
    socket.on('rooms:App\\Events\\UserJoined', data =>{

       this.usersCounter = data.users;
    });
    socket.on('rooms:App\\Events\\UserLeft', data =>{

      this.usersCounter = data.users;
    });
```

this code above updates all the counters of the v-for rooms list-items not just this.currentOne when the user clicks the join or leave button and the event fires.

thanks in advance.

Comment: What does your `v-for` list in your template look like? [Are you using a key?](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key)

Comment: this is my component: 
       
     <room v-for="room in rooms" :user="currentUser" :joined="joined" :key="room.id" :room="room"></room>

Comment: Do you have multiple counters? A counter per room? Please add more code. The `room` component and the component that's using the room would help.

Comment: Yes I do have multiple counter, a counter per room

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't believe it is that simple, I just added an if condition and everything worked fine. actually I feel very stupid already :D :D

```
socket.on('room:App\\Events\\UserJoined', function(data) {
      if(this.room.id == data.payload.roomId){
        this.usersCount = data.payload.usersCount;
      }
    }.bind(this));
```

Thanks to everyone who viewed my question trying to help